# Jetta intermittent starting problem

Tags: electrical, vw, jetta

I have a 2007 Jetta with 75k miles on it. What I'm running into is that out-of-the blue, the car will not start. Generally, it turns over, but never starts. One time, it started but shut itself off after 3 seconds. Warning lights that flash are the steering wheel indicator and sometimes the traction control and immobilizer lights. I replaced the battery hoping that that would fix it, but it hasn't. Notably, the engine light is usually on when starting and goes off after 3 seconds, but now it doesn't go on at all.

The issue first started a few weeks ago, but I could successfully start it 15 min later. No issues for 2 weeks, until the traction control light came on and stayed on while driving. Nothing for a few days, and then suddenly could not start again (tried over a period of 3 days). Towed to a shop, where it started after two days. Any advice?? Thanks!!

Comment: Is this gas or diesel? Which engine exactly? Was thinking it might be a fuel pump issue, but don't know.

Comment: 2.5L gas non-turbo

Comment: When it doesn't start, can you hear the fuel pump run when you cycle the key to on (not start but "on") and then off? You should hear a faint whine for about 5 seconds with each cycle.

Comment: There are two different situations at play - the general inability to start, and the "starts, but shuts off after 3 seconds due to immobilizer". Aside from the immobilizer code, what other codes does it throw?

Comment: mikes Yes, I think the fuel pump was running. I was hearing a faint noise that sounded like the engine fan as well.

@LynnCrumbling I'm not sure of codes, since I don't have a reader, but my mechanic mentioned seeing a low voltage code at one point.

update: they've been able to seemingly replicate the start/not-start experience by fiddling around with the fuses (and the order they're put in) in the fusebox behind the battery. An intermittent electrical connection like that would seem to make sense with what I experienced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final solution: a wire in the wire harness between the steering wheel and fusebox was partially corroded.